Enable SSL connection to RDS postgres database with Google Looker postgres connector
I am using Google Looker to connect to an RDS database hosted in a private VPC in AWS.
Now that I have achieved this I would like to secure it further with SSL.
I have created an RDS database running postgres 14.13 in a private subnet and configured RDS proxy.
Provisioned an AWS network load balancer to provide a public endpoint for Google Looker to connect to.
I have whitelisted the Looker IP addresses provided for Google Looker.
From Google Looker I have entered the load balancer DNS name, target database and the username/password (for the user configured with RDS proxy).
I am able to connect successfully to the database.
Now I am attempting to enable SSL when connecting a postgres database (AWS RDS) to Google looker.
This requires "configuration files". I am attempting to use the bundled PEM files provided by AWS for postgres databases as described in the AWS article Using SSL with a PostgreSQL DB instance

The connection no longer works and fails with generic error messages.

Does RDS support this approach to SSL postgres connections?
As per Google's documentation:
Note: Looker Studio expects a PKCS-8 client key format
However it seems that RDS only provides public certificate files (in PEM format).
Should RDS proxy handle SSL instead?
From AWS:
"RDS Proxy can also ensure that your session uses TLS/SSL between your client and the RDS Proxy endpoint. To have RDS Proxy do so, specify the requirement on the client side. SSL session variables are not set for SSL connections to a database using RDS Proxy."
I would like to know if the above approach is supported, and if not, can the connection be considered secure without SSL enabled.
Any help would be appreciated.
